# Object Literal: Dynamic DOM not accessible

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

I haven't fully grasp the fundamentals of Object Literal in Javascript, so here's an example of my issue. I have created an AJAX function `post()` that returns `<div id="foo"></div>` inside `<div id=test></div>` to simulate my problem.

```
var a = {
    static: $('#test'),
    dynamic: $('#foo'),
    test: {
        load: function(){
            post().done(function(r){
                a.static.html(r.testing)
            })
         }
    }
}

var b = {
    test1: function(m){
        a.static.html(m)
    },
    test2: function(m){
        a.dynamic.html(m)
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is this:

1. `b.test1('Hello')` will write to HTML accordingly, because the initial HTML file contains `#test`. This is totally understandable.
2. `b.test2('Hello')` will not write, because I don't know why, and here is where I need some explanation.

Here's the fiddle for your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/tfYGR/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the expression `dynamic: $('#foo')` is evaluated at the beginning of the script execution when the element with id `foo` is not created so `$('#foo')` will return an empty jQuery object.

The `#foo` element is created only when the `test1` method is called.

A possible solution is to store the dynamic element selector in `a.dynamic` instead of trying to store the jQuery object like

```
dynamic: '#foo'
```

then

```
$(a.dynamic).html(m)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LYcaw/)

In the above case the selector `#foo` is not evaluated till the `test2` is called, by that time `test1` has added the target element to the dom

Comment: Great! I'm used to this before Object Literal, and I missed this. Thank you for the clarification. Does other solution exist too?

Comment: @rolodex no other one that I'm aware of

Answer (score -1):

It is because of the asynchronous nature of the ajax calls. When you make an ajax call, the browser will continue to execute the script without waiting for the response. Here you get the  through the ajax response. Hence a.dynamic will be an empty object.

Solution has two parts:combine both to get the complete solution

Part 1)Do not initialise a.dynamic to $('#foo') because at the time of creation of a, $('#foo') will return an empty element. Initialise to '#foo'.

Part 2)You have to call b.test2('Hello') in the success callback of the ajax response.The previous answer worked because they have tried to imitate the ajax response,in which they return the result immediately, but in the real time we will get the ajax response only after the delay, so the previous answer will not work . To ensure proper execution you have to call b.test2('Hello') in the success call back of the ajax response .

Comment: I think you're confused. 1 - You say initialize to `#foo` instead of `$("#foo")` whereas in your statement #2 contradicts #1. @Arun's answer works fine either in true AJAX call or simulation, and it didn't have to be invoke in the success call to make it work.

Comment: Actually i meant point 1 and point 2 to be two parts of the same solution. It should be like 
       b.test2=function(m){
        $(a.dynamic).html(m)
       }
In arun's solution b.test2 will be immediately executed after a.test.load . Hence if it had been an ajax call, there are chances that $('#foo') will be undefined still. Hence it is a must to call b.test2 in the success callback of the ajax request. Correct me if i am wrong - @rolodex

Comment: I guess in order for others to understand your theory, why don't you post an example code. TL;DR!